# Animate borders to follow each other css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make a border surrounding an HTML element to loop. You can find it in this [pen](https://codepen.io/Tes3awy/pen/vYByEJW) that I managed to make it run once correctly. But, if I add `infinite` property to the `animation` it shows all after the first cycle. And this is not what I want in this case. How can I make the lines follow each other infinitely where only one line is visible?

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 25%);
}

.heading-one {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-border {
  opacity: 0;
}

.inner-border:nth-child(1) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate1 1s ease-in alternate;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.inner-border:nth-child(2) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -3px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate2 1s ease-in 1s alternate;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.inner-border:nth-child(3) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: 0;
  height: 6px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate3 1s ease-in 2s alternate;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.inner-border:nth-child(4) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate4 1s ease-in 3s alternate;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="heading-one">We Redefine Interior Designing
    <span class="inner-border"></span>
    <span class="inner-border"></span>
    <span class="inner-border"></span>
    <span class="inner-border"></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try SVG? https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

Comment: @ManojKumar Unfortunately, not an option for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the timing offset, integrate the offset into the animation itself. In this way, the `@keyframes` declarations describe full loops and so can be animated continuously:

```
.inner-border:nth-child(1) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate1 4s ease-in 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    left: -80px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.inner-border:nth-child(2) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -3px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate2 4s ease-in 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    top: -80px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    top: -80px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.inner-border:nth-child(3) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: 0;
  height: 6px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate3 4s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    right: -80px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    right: -80px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.inner-border:nth-child(4) {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate4 4s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -80px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    bottom: -80px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. Works like a charm (Y)